# Recently adopted 4 month old pomeranian puppy, I am concerned about his behavior

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, adoption

He is a 4 month unneutered male pomernanian. He seems to have a lot of energy and wants to socialize and play all the time. He isn't trained the way he should've been. I have had him for a week now. The first day, he did not whine nor cry. He isn't potty trained and had numerous accidents. The second to fourth day he gotten use to me and started interacting. He's much more shy and "serious" with my boy friend. He is very addicted to treats, that I noticed. Every time I reach for one to start training him he goes into an absolute frenzy.

Fifth day, I noticed he is whining now, when left in the playpen and crate, when left alone, when I leave for work. He doesn't whine with my boy friend or very minimal. I started seeing some aggression, anxiety and isn't eating as well. He still has accidents, but is a little better than before.

Sixth day, I am distraught. He has chewed on the floor board, peeing everywhere, doesn't want to go in his crate, or play pen. He isn't eating his kibble, only wet food. Nipping at face kind of like rushing at it. Biting hands (probably from teething) and cries whenever not in my presence.

Did I give him too much attention or not enough? Should I leave him alone not free roamin in my sight and to the minimal interactions (walk, play, feed, potty, train) and have him crated? I could use some advice.

Comment: Its a puppy, puppies have accidents, they cry and nibble...train him, get a trainer  to help/teach you if needed..crate training will help loads

Answer (score 1):

I’m not an expert but I think maybe he is calling for attention.

I babysat a dog with this problem once and we trained her not to bite. One thing you can try is to put him on a leash and tie it to a tree. You need to put you hand out and let him bite you. If he does, then you go somewhere he can’t see you. Return to him after a minute or until he starts whining and keep putting ur hand in front of him until he doesn’t bite you anymore. And when he bites you, yelp like a dog really loudly like you are in pain.

And he might be more submissive around your boyfriend because he sees him as dominant. I don’t really have a solution for the peeing issue but I hope this helps. I forgot to add that you should try tying him somewhere out in the open and that this should be a place he isn’t familiar with, like out in the driveway.

Answer (score 0):

Go and find a dog trainer near you. They can help you a lot better then some internet stranger.